# How to get chosen effect on DragDropCompleted

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, telerik

I have a RadTreeView (treeview) and a RadGridView (gridview). The user should be able to move elements from the gridview to the treeview and change the effect of the drag&drop action by using the shift or control key (like in Windows Explorer).

In the GiveFeedback event the effect is set according to the pressed key and also the visualization shows the expected behavior. But in the Drop event (on the treeview) and in the DragDropCompleted event (on the gridview) the effect is set to All, therefore I'm not able to decide if I have to remove the Element from the current list.

Am I missing something?

XAML:

```
    <telerik:RadTreeView AllowDrop="True"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFolder,
                                                Mode=TwoWay}"
                         SelectionMode="Single">
      <telerik:RadTreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Folder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
          <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       local:TreeItemDropBehavior.IsEnabled="True" />
          </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </telerik:RadTreeView.Resources>
    </telerik:RadTreeView>
    <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Column="1"
                         AllowDrop="True"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                         CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                         CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                         FontSize="12"
                         IsFilteringAllowed="False"
                         IsReadOnly="True"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFolder.Elements}"
                         RowHeight="32"
                         RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                         SelectionMode="Multiple"
                         ShowGroupPanel="False"
                         local:GridViewDragDropBehavior.IsEnabled="True"
                         telerik:DragDropManager.AllowCapturedDrag="True"
                         telerik:DragDropManager.AllowDrag="True">
      <telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
              <DataTemplate x:Key="DraggedItemTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="Dragging: " />
                  <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding CurrentDraggedItems.Count}" />
                  <TextBlock Text=" Element(s)" />
                </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ResourceDictionary>
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
      <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="100"
                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                    Header="Name" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="250"
                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"
                                    Header="Description" />
      </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

GridViewDragDropBehavior:

```
  public class GridViewDragDropBehavior
  {
    public RadGridView AssociatedControl { get; set; }

    private void SubscribeToDragDropEvents()
    {
      DragDropManager.AddDragInitializeHandler(AssociatedControl, OnDragInitialize);
      DragDropManager.AddGiveFeedbackHandler(AssociatedControl, OnGiveFeedback);
      DragDropManager.AddDragDropCompletedHandler(AssociatedControl, OnDragDropCompleted);
      DragDropManager.AddDragOverHandler(AssociatedControl, OnDragOver);
    }

    private void UnsubscribeFromDragDropEvents()
    {
      DragDropManager.RemoveDragInitializeHandler(AssociatedControl, OnDragInitialize);
      DragDropManager.RemoveGiveFeedbackHandler(AssociatedControl, OnGiveFeedback);
      DragDropManager.RemoveDragDropCompletedHandler(AssociatedControl, OnDragDropCompleted);
      DragDropManager.RemoveDragOverHandler(AssociatedControl, OnDragOver);
    }

    private void OnDragInitialize(object sender, DragInitializeEventArgs e)
    {
      DropIndicationDetails details = new DropIndicationDetails();
      var gridView = sender as RadGridView;
      details.DragSource = gridView.ItemsSource;

      var items = gridView.SelectedItems;
      details.CurrentDraggedItems = items;

      IDragPayload dragPayload = DragDropPayloadManager.GeneratePayload(null);

      dragPayload.SetData("DraggedData", items);
      dragPayload.SetData("DropDetails", details);

      e.Data = dragPayload;

      e.DragVisual = new DragVisual { Content = details, ContentTemplate = AssociatedControl.Resources["DraggedItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate };
      e.DragVisualOffset = new Point(e.RelativeStartPoint.X + 10, e.RelativeStartPoint.Y);
      e.AllowedEffects = DragDropEffects.All;
    }

    private void OnGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("GridViewDragDropBehavior.OnGiveFeedback {0}", e.Effects);
      e.SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow);
      e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnDragDropCompleted(object sender, DragDropCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("GridViewDragDropBehavior.OnDragDropCompleted: {0}", e.Effects);
      var data = DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, "DraggedData") as IList;
      var details = DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, "DropDetails");
      Debug.WriteLine(e.Effects);

      // Remove Element from source list if drag drop effect is move
      /*if (e.Effects == DragDropEffects.Move)
      {
        var collection = (details as DropIndicationDetails).DragSource as IList;
        foreach(var element in data)
        {
          collection.Remove(element);
        }
      }*/
    }

    private void OnDragOver(object sender, Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.DragEventArgs e)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("GridViewDragDropBehavior.OnDragOver: {0}", e.Effects);
      e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
      e.Handled = true;
    }
  }
```

TreeItemDropBehavior.cs:

```
  public class TreeItemDropBehavior
  {
    protected virtual void Initialize()
    {
      DragDropManager.AddGiveFeedbackHandler(AssociatedObject, OnGiveFeedback);
      DragDropManager.AddDropHandler(AssociatedObject, OnDrop);
    }

    protected virtual void CleanUp()
    {
      DragDropManager.RemoveGiveFeedbackHandler(AssociatedObject, OnGiveFeedback);
      DragDropManager.RemoveDropHandler(AssociatedObject, OnDrop);
    }

    private void OnGiveFeedback(object sender, Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("TreeItemDropBehavior.OnGiveFeedback {0}", e.Effects);
      e.SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow);
      e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnDrop(object sender, Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.DragEventArgs e)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("TreeItemDropBehavior.OnDrop: {0}", e.Effects);

      if (e.Effects != DragDropEffects.None)
      {
        var destinationItem = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).ParentOfType<RadTreeViewItem>();
        var data = DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, "DraggedData") as IList;
        var details = DragDropPayloadManager.GetDataFromObject(e.Data, "DropDetails") as DropIndicationDetails;

        if (destinationItem != null)
        {
          foreach (var element in data)
          {
            (destinationItem.DataContext as Folder).Elements.Add(element as Element);
          }

          e.Handled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: shortened code, complete sample can be found here: https://github.com/rolandbaer/DragAndDropToTreeView (needs of courses the telerik library for WPF)